# Visual Studio 2013 large solution build shows errors that aren't there

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-5

The problem I have with Visual Studio 2013 (latest) is that it compiles the solution and shows about 5-6 errors that never go away. There are 30 projects.

In this case it's missing references:

> Error 37  The type or namespace name '...' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

So a project seemingly could not be built.

**The problem is, *there are no errors*, Intellisense does not show any errors, and the application runs fine.**

A cleanup + rebuild will resolve the issue, but then after rebuilding a few times without a cleanup/restart will bring back the same non-existent errors in the Error List window.

**Curiously, the problem persists across restarts, reboots, solution cleanups (including deleting obj/Debug) folders).**

Have not been able to find other questions related to this.

Does anyone have an idea why this it, and how to get rid of the psycho errors?
Resharper 9.1 is installed.

Comment: `Resharper 9.1 is installed.` - Does it reproduce without it?

Comment: @HighCore same thing happens without RS9.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting all your .suo files.